# Is it possible to have PATH environment have a relative path in zsh?

Tags: linux, zsh

For example, I have a lot of different nodejs projects and they have different package versions. I want to have `./node_modules/.bin` add to PATH so I can easily execute package under the current directory.

I'm using zsh and I'm happy to try some complex solutions (for example, maybe register a function to try find that command under a relative directory when encountering a `command not found` error)

Comment: Note that relative paths are resolves based on the process's working directory, which is not necessarily the same as a project directory, or the directory a script/program is in, or anything like that.

Comment: Technically, it is, but don't do it unless you are fully aware of the consequences. It is after all a security hole. Always ask yourself why you can't do with absolute pathes....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. You could already add the current directory (`.`) to your PATH (but that's usually a bad idea). Since `.` works, why wouldn't any other relative path?

Here's a demo showcasing that this works indeed:

```
$ mkdir scripts
$ cat <<EOF > scripts/hello
> #!/bin/sh
> echo 'hello!'
> EOF
$ chmod +x scripts/hello
$ PATH="$PATH:scripts"
$ hello
hello!
$ cd scripts
$ hello
bash: scripts/hello: No such file or directory
$ cd /tmp
$ hello
bash: scripts/hello: No such file or directory
```

Comment: lol, I just assumed that it isn't possible. Thanks!!